# How to add AndroidX components in Android Studio UI designer?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to add [`NestedScrollView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/widget/NestedScrollView) to my activity, but Studio says it is going to use legacy supprot

[image]

How to use non-legacy version?

Comment: Does your project use androidx ?

Comment: post up your gradle dependencies